# DIR-601 Wireless Router 404 redirect

Tags: router, dns, http-status-code-404

How can I stop my DLink DIR-601 router from directing to `http://dlinkrouter/error-404.htm` if I enter a bogus address?

Example:
asdasdasdzxczxczxc.com

As a developer I want to see the standard 404 page.

Please note - this is not the redirect which occurs when "Advanced DNS" is checked and routed to http://www1.dlinksearch.com/

This issue was to do with entering a bogus DNS address and still getting redirected by the router.  After searching the internet it appears this is built in to the router.  I just called DLink and their customer support is clueless.

This is what happens in Firefox:

[image]

This is what happens in Safari:

[image]

If there is some setting that I can change in setup it would be great to hear. I wonder if all routers do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the official firmware doesn't have a option to disable it, you can always try to install a custom firmware like OpenWRT (http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-600) or DD-WRT (http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DIR-601). They don't mess with your DNS settings unless you ask them, so it should show the default 404 page.

As a bonus, you will have a powerful opensource firmware that will allow you to do some cool things like a Music Player or IPv6.

Another option is to force DNS settings on your computer. If your router doesn't force the devices on network to connect to his DNS, this should work too.

Comment: m45t3r you beat me to it. I had a look around and everyone pretty much complained about the same thing, and someone on Dlink forum even said "You can't turn this off" so... ddwrt or other custom firmware, or exchange to a different product seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks! It's great to see a solution available. I will check this out.